# extra \x0D appended when echo \0x0A

Tags: shell-script, terminal, tty, serial-port, newlines

I am trying to send some hex values to a tty port `/dev/ttyS2`. When I use `echo` or `printf \x0A` it will print an extra `\x0D` before the `\x0A`.

```
i=1 
a=$(printf "\xAA\xEE\x0A\x%02x" $i)
echo -ne   "$a"  > /dev/ttyS2
```

I get this on the terminal/serial port -- note the extra 0D. How can I remove that?

[image]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to disable newline conversion:

```
stty -F /dev/ttyS2 -onlcr
```

or, for strict POSIX [`stty`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/stty.html):

```
stty -onlcr < /dev/ttyS2
```

Comment: `a=$(printf "\xB2\x00\x01" $i)
    echo -ne  "$a"  > /dev/ttyS2`  now the \x00 is not printed using echo

Comment: @dmSherazi, bash's `printf` builtin understands those `\xXX` sequences and expand them to the corresponding bytes. `bash` variables cannot contain NUL bytes (`zsh` is the only shell that can). Here, you'd need `a=$(printf '\\xB2\\x00\\x%02x' "$i")` and `printf %b "$a" > /dev/ttyS2` (or preferably switch to octal if you want to be portable).

Comment: `stty` does not have an option `-F`, it operates on `stdin`.

Comment: @schily, not the POSIX specification of the `stty` command, but several implementations support `-F`, including GNU, busybox or ast-open. [Added so that the device could be opened in non-blocking mode](https://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/coreutils.git/commit/?id=c4b7f217a529221cb653399d65a6666e00576e1c) which shells can't do with redirections.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas The only known constraint where a normal open for a tty blocks is when you try to open the dial in variant of the tty.  If you however set the tty modes before the carrier detect line is set active, there is no grant that the tty modes survive that status change. BTW: the `stty` built into `ksh93` does not support `-F` if you only check versions that have been published by David Korn.

Comment: @schily, actually, ast-open's stty does support a `-F` (and has since 2010 / ksh93u), but it takes a fd number as argument, not a file path (GNU stty added -F in 1998, BSDs had -f for that long before that)

Answer (score 13):

If you want bytes to be transmitted as-is across a serial connection both ways, you need to tell the system it's not  to be used as a terminal device, either by detaching the tty line discipline from it or by issuing:

```
stty raw -echo < /dev/ttyS2
```

In your case, it was the `onlcr` attribute which is enabled by default on tty device that was causing the LF to CRLF conversion on output. You can disable *all* output processing including `ocrnl` with `stty -opost`, but that leaves all the input processing for data transmitted in the other direction.

You're not indicating which shell, `echo` or `printf` implementation you're using but note that the `-n`, `-e` options are not standard, and the behaviour of `printf` or `echo` when an argument contains `\x` is unspecified.

Several implementations of `printf` in their format argument expand `\xHH` to the byte of value 0xHH.

In those

```
printf "\xAA\xEE\x0A\x%02x" $i
```

Would expand `\xAA` to the byte 0xAA and for `\x` would either expand that to byte 0 or to `\x` literally or complain that hex digits are missing. So you'd end up with `<0xaa><0xee><LF>\x01` in `$a` for instance.

Some `echo` implementations do also interpret `\xHH` sequences (some only when passed a `-e` option).

Here, if you wanted to be portable, you'd do:

```
a=$(printf '\\252\\356\\012\\%03o' "$i")
printf "$a" > /dev/ttyS2
```

Or:

```
a=$(printf '\\0252\\0356\\0012\\0%03o' "$i")
printf %b "$a" > /dev/ttyS2
```

(standard `printf` supports `\ooo` octal sequences in the format, and a `%b` format which is meant to emulate the kind of expansions some `echo` implementations do with or without `-e`, and where the octal sequences are expressed as `\0ooo`).

You also want to make sure the first `printf` doesn't output a NUL byte, as except for `zsh`, shells cannot store NUL bytes in their variable (don't do <strike>`a=$(printf '\0 or \x00 or \u0000')`</strike> for instance).

With `zsh`:

```
bytes=(0xaa 0xee 0x0a $i)
set +o multibyte
printf %s ${(#)bytes} > /dev/ttyS2
```

That data could be stored in a variable with either:

```
printf -v data %s ${(#)bytes}
```

or

```
data=${(#j[])bytes}
```

But more generally, if you want to manipulate data with arbitrary byte values, you may want to use a proper programming language, even if it's an interpreted one like `perl` or  `python`.

Another approach would be to use tools like `xxd` that can convert back and forth between a binary form and a text hex dump.

```
printf aaee0a%02d "$i" | xxd -p -r > /dev/ttyS1
```